# How to display a dialog to wait for user to continue in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, dialog

I have an AsyncTask that does a bunch of stuff in the doInBackground() portion, and in between that bunch of stuff, I need to wait for the user to physically do something before I can continue. How do I popup some dialog for the user to click OK before continuing?

Thanks!

Comment: At the end of Asynctask , are you waiting for a user input  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in between that bunch of stuff, I need to wait for the user to
>   physically do something before I can continue.

You aren't supposed to do that in doInBackground method, You need to do that in onPostExecute(); Interaction with the user should be done in onPostExecute.

What you can do here?

Divide your code in 2 parts, perform the code that has to be done until users Interaction in the background in doInBackground, make user Interact  do that in onPostExecute, after that for rest of remaining code you can use another AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... p_params)
        {
            // Your background code
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // Display Progress dialog with cancelable false
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object p_result)
        {
            // Dismiss Progress dialog
            super.onPostExecute(p_result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put wait dialog in between doInBackground section then you can try following code:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
                dialog.setTitle("Demo");
                Button button = new Button(activity);
                button.setText("Press For Process..");
                dialog.setContentView(button);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Perform Task",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // You can perform task whatever want to do after
                        // on user press the button
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Best among all answers available here ! should be accepted